# Using Closure Templates with Clojurescript

Tags: clojurescript

Is it possible to use Google Closure Templates with Clojurescript?

I have looked around but haven't found any information regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the Soy Templates are compiled down to JavaScript functions, you should be able to use it without any problem. Look here for a general explanation of how to use external JavaScript libraries in ClojureScript:

http://lukevanderhart.com/2011/09/30/using-javascript-and-clojurescript.html

You should also compile your templates with this flag: `--shouldProvideRequireSoyNamespaces`, look [here](https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/javascript_usage#usageclosurelibrary) for more information.

As another option you could use a templating library written for ClojureScript. There are at least two great libraries: [Dommy](https://github.com/Prismatic/dommy) and [Enfocus](https://github.com/ckirkendall/enfocus).

Comment: Unfortunately Dommy does not work with lighttable, otherwise I would use it

Answer (score 1):

The Google Closure templates should work in ClojureScript without much hassle.  Try referencing the goog.whatever namespace at the top of your ClojureScript file like normal.  If you're not using advanced mode compilation, then reference your cljs file's namespace with a goog.require in the HTML page.  Otherwise, you don't need goog.require when compiling in advanced mode.

So if you have a project named foo, a ClojureScript file named bar, and you want to use goog.dom without advanced mode, you could try something like this:

cljs file

```
(ns foo.bar
  (:require [goog.dom :as dom]))
```

in the index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/compiled.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    goog.require('foo.bar'); 
</script>
```

The [twitterbuzz sample](https://github.com/emezeske/clojurescript/tree/master/samples/twitterbuzz) gives a good example of this.

Comment: I looked at the link in TwitterBuzz. Which files should I be looking at that are templates?

Comment: Opps, I totally misunderstood the question, sorry.  If you're trying to do soy templates with Google Closure there is an [older Clojure library](https://github.com/levand/clj-soy).  I don't know how to do this in cljs but there is an [example page](https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/javascript_usage) that talks about templating with JavaScript that could be useful.

Comment: Ah, cool library, thanks. No worries if you misunderstood the question, I upvoted your answer anyway